# pass php variables javascript window location

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to destroy all form sessions as follows:
i have a sidenav.php bar, when the user clicks on it, it goes to this page:

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['applicationID']);
session_destroy();
echo'<html><script>window.location="index.php?url=newapplication&id="'.$userid.';</script></html>';
?>
```

which in turn bring up the new application form, however, the `"$userid"` fails to echo. it comes back as blank. any ideas?

Comment: You haven't defined `$userid`.

Comment: it is actually declared in my index page.  in my index page when the url==newapplication, it brings up the file to be included.

Comment: What Jay says.. Also, you might want to take a look at how to do your redirection in PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/a/768472/3492835

Comment: i can't user headers has it has already been send. thanks.

Comment: What about using ob_start();

Comment: Ok, clear. Does this script output anything to your console? ````echo '<html><script>console.log("'.$userid.'");</script></html>';````

Comment: If it is declared in your index page when are you including this?

Answer (score 1):

**$userid ** NEEDS (you have no option) to be defined BEFORE you can use it.

Whatever you have defined in your main script will stay there because that script has finished his execution time.

You can **pass** that value via either **GET**, **POST**, **SESSION** or **COOKIE**. Otherwise you will have to dig on your database for that username but then again, you need to "keep" a session or a number to "go back to" in order to search for it.

What you are actually trying to do could work as follows if you **HAVE** the **userid** variable defined in **SESSION**:

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['applicationID']);
echo'<html><script>window.location="index.php?url=newapplication&id='.$_SESSION['userid'].'"';
session_destroy();
echo '</script></html>';
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

You have closed `window.location` before `$userid`.The output of your above code will be

```
<html><script>window.location="index.php?url=newapplication&id="the_value_of_$userid;</script></html>
```

Use the code below

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['applicationID']);
session_destroy();
echo'<html><script>window.location="index.php?url=newapplication&id='.$userid.'";</script></html>';
?>
```

Hope this helps you